# Menu rollovers flicker - How to account for Mouse Leave activity

Tags: delphi, canvas, paint, mousemove

I'm building a custom menu and have been having some issues with the hover states on the links. Now, after much tinkering I've managed to get my menu rectangle responding properly to mouse hover states - Almost.

I can't for the life of me work out how to get them to revert back to normal once the mouse has left the rectangle - it remains in it's hovered state. Moving onto a different rectangle resets correctly, anywhere else on the canvas is treated as still being in last rectangle hovered over.

My MouseMove procedure.

```
procedure TOC_MenuPanel.MouseMove(Shift:TShiftState; X,Y:Integer);
var
  i : integer;
begin
 pt := Mouse.CursorPos;
 pt := ScreenToClient(pt);
 for i := 0 to High(MenuRects) do
   begin
     if PtInRect(MenuRects[i], Point(X, Y)) then
        begin
           chosenRect := i;
           Refresh;
        end
     else
        begin
           chosenRect := -1;
        end;
   end;
   inherited;
end;
```

And my paint procedure:

```
procedure TOC_MenuPanel.Paint;
var
  // TextStyle: TTextStyle;
  R, itemR: TRect;
  count : Integer;
  x1,y1,x2,y2 : Integer;

begin
  // Set length of array
  SetLength(MenuRects, fLinesText.Count);

// Set TRect to Canvas size
R := Rect(5, 5, Width-5, Height-5);
x1 := 10;
y1 := 10;
x2 := Width-10;

inherited Paint;

with Canvas do begin
  // Set fonts
  Font.Height := MenuFontHeight;
  Font.Color := clWhite;

  // Draw outerbox
  GradientFill(R, clLtGray, clWhite, gdVertical);

  // Draw inner boxes
  if fLinesText.Count = 0 then exit
     else
  for count := 0 to fLinesText.Count - 1 do
     begin
       // Define y2
       y2 := TextHeight(fLinesText.strings[count])*2;

       itemR := Rect(x1, y1, x2, y2*(count+1));
       Pen.color := clGray;

     // Test against chosenRect value and compare mouse position against that of the rectangle
       if (chosenRect = count) and (PtInRect(MenuRects[count], pt)) then
          Brush.color := stateColor[bttn_on]
       else
          Brush.color := stateColor[bttn_off];

       Rectangle(itemR);

       // Push rectangle info to array
       MenuRects[count] := itemR;

       // Draw the text
       TextRect(itemR, x1+5,  y1+5, fLinesText.strings[count]);

       // inc y1 for positioning the next box
       y1 := y1+y2;
     end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: That's what I [`tried to comment`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23917365/freepascal-how-do-i-change-the-colour-of-a-tpaint-object-on-mouseover#comment36836435_23917770) yesterday. You should invalidate the control only when you move to a different item, not with each mouse move.

Comment: Aye I remember, Tlama, am still a bit of a noob with Pascal, but getting there slowly. Just finding my way through one step at a time currently!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was in the MouseMove procedure, the following produces the correct behaviour:

```
procedure TOC_MenuPanel.MouseMove(Shift:TShiftState; X,Y:Integer);
var
  i : integer;
begin
 // Get cursor position within the control
 pt := Mouse.CursorPos;
 pt := ScreenToClient(pt);

 // loop through Array of Rectangles
 for i := 0 to High(MenuRects) do
   begin
     if PtInRect(MenuRects[i], Point(X, Y)) then
        begin
           chosenRect := i;
           Break; // If statement evaluates to true, stop the loop
        end
     else
        begin
           chosenRect := -1;
        end;

   end;
   Refresh; // Refresh the canvs
inherited;
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

The painting that you do in the mouse move event handler is immediately lost because you force a paint cycle by calling `Invalidate`. As a general rule, it is best to do all painting to the screen in a paint cycle. In some scenarios it can make sense to paint outside of a paint cycle, but it is notoriously hard to get right.

So, I suspect that you need to move all the drawing code into your paint routine, wherever and whatever that is. So, in the mouse move event you need to invalidate the form or paint box or whatever it is that paints the scene. Then in your paint routine you use `GetCursorPos`, or `Mouse.Pos` or similar to find the position of the cursor. And you use that to determine how to paint the scene. You may well find it more effective, in terms of flicker avoidance, to paint to an off-screen bitmap and then blit that onto the canvas.

Now, if you invalidate on every single mouse move then you might find the painting burden to be excessive. So perhaps you should keep track of the state of the most recently painted scene. Test in the mouse move handler whether or not the new state differs from the most recently painted. Only if it does differ would you force a paint cycle.